# How to dynamically change TRIX rich text editor toolbar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, trix

I have AngularJS app where I use trix rich text editor via this directive
https://github.com/sachinchoolur/angular-trix

I have my own directive for the toolbar that I have customized (sometimes show some buttons, sometimes not etc). The toolbar loads but the TRIX editor does not link the buttons to actions.

If I move my custom toolbar away from my directive, the buttons are correctly linked. The problem, I believe, is that because the trix-toolbar is loaded later than the directive where the trix-editor is, the buttons with attributes data-trix-attribute etc are not in dom yet when trix searches for them. I don't want to embed trix editor into same directive where the toolbar is because that would complicate the initialization of the trix a lot and managing files etc.

This is just my short code (jade)

```
trix-toolbar(id="my-trix-toolbar", my-trix-toolbar, no-bold)

trix-editor(angular-trix, toolbar="my-trix-toolbar")
```

Here, I think that the trix-editor is loaded before the trix-toolbar content and therefore it fails.

And my-trix-toolbar is a directive mainly copying the dom structure of the original toolbar

Comment: I couldn't give the answer to title, but I solved the problem by transcluding trix-editor to my-trix-toolbar.

Comment: You should write up the solution that you used.